# ¿Cómo almacenar contenido html con con etiquetas php en una variable?

Tags: php, php7

Como podría almacenar lo anteriormente dicho en una variable **php**, tengo el siguiente código

```
<?php
    $data = 
?>

 <!-- etiqueta html-->
 <div>

    <?php
        //ejecutar ciclo for
        for($i=0; $i<11; $i++)
        {
            echo $i;
        }
    ?>

  <!-- etiqueta html-->
 </div>

<?php
    
    //llamar a función y pasar la variable data
    proccess($data);
    
    //declarar función
    function proccess($data)
    {
        //do something
    }

?>
```

Como se puede observar en mi código la variable **data** pretende guardar contenido **html** pero dentro hay una función **for** la cual la realizo cerrando y abriendo etiquetas **php** para que "funcionen" pero me salen errores en las etiquetas de apertura **php**.

¿Habrá alguna forma de hacer esto, o estoy intentando hacer algo que es incorrecto o que no debería hacerce?

Comment: Intenta imprimiendo las etiquetas del `div` con un `echo`, algo asi: `echo '<div>';`. Saludos.

Comment: Gracias!! @JosueArriola

Answer (score 2, accepted):

intentalo de esta manera.

```
<?php

$data = "<div>";
    for($i=0; $i<11; $i++)
    {
        $data .= $i;
    }
$data .= "</div>";

?>

<?php
    
    //llamar a función y pasar la variable data
    proccess($data);
    
    //declarar función
    function proccess($data)
    {
        //do something
    }

?>
```

Comment: Gracias, me funcionó!! @AlanGuillermo

Answer (score 1):

Estás manejando mal el uso de echo dentro de una variable, recuerda que echo es para que imprimas el valor en pantalla.

```
<?php 
    $data = '<div>';
    for($i=0; $i<11; $i++):
        $data .= $i; 
    endfor;
    $data .= '</div>'; 
?>

/* Este sería el output */
<div>012345678910</div>
```

Esa variable $data que se generó  ya puedes pasarla a alguna función para renderizar el contenido o lo que tengas que hacer.

Comment: Grácias por tu obervación @Deilusia lo tomaré muy en cuenta!!!